# how to Zoom In/Out using Robotium?

Tags: android-layout, robotium

i try to open web browser apk, open one web page.
is it possible to ZOOM IN/OUT of this web page using robotium ?

and i try to open one docx file using open Office apk automation using robotium.
is it possible to ZOOM IN/OUT for this document page using robotium ?

Any one have solution then please help me.

Answer (score 1):

As far i know there is no functionality like that in Robotium.

Answer (score 1):

For a web page you can use the zoomIn() method of a webview that you have gotten a reference to using any number of the ways you can with robotium.

To be able to use this method you will have to cast the view you got from robotium to a WebView and to perform the zoom you will have to run on the uithread. The code would look something like:

```
final WebView webView = (WebView) Solo.getView(R.id.web_views_id);
instrumentation.runOnMainSync(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            webView.zoomIn()
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but i am using Default Android Web Browser, Not WebView. So i can not use your above code for this default browser page. Thanks again for your best try.

Comment: Is your instrumentation target the android web browser or in the course of testing your application a web browser gets loaded? if it is the latter then you will be out of luck to do anything to it. Is there a reason you want to test the zoom in zoom out functionality? It seems like this should not be a test anyway because it is testing functionality that you know works, or are you trying to test something happens on zoom?

Comment: i want to test zoom in/out functionality in android default web browser only. So, i resign android browser apk from system/app/ and try to automate zoom in/out on any one web page which contains text of 5 pages.